# Tensorflow Install and Bezel Problems at Last Step

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, ubuntu-16.04

Trying to install Tensorflow with Bezel and having a tough time at this final build step. Ubuntu 16.04, Cuda 8, cuDNN 5.1.

Here are the official install instructions I'm following: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#ConfigureInstallation

```
bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package 

ERROR: Skipping '//tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package':
error loading package 'tensorflow/tools/pip_package': Encountered
error while reading extension file 'cuda/build_defs.bzl': no such
package '@local_config_cuda//cuda': Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I'm not sure what the '//tensorflow' directory is, but it actually picks up packages if I use '~/tensorflow' instead. It still fails though trying to pick up more than 3, and I'm assuming it's because of some path issue. I could really use another set of eyes.

Comment: Can you add more of the error message? It is cut off before the bazel traceback.